# How can I improve my question?

Tags: discussion, votes

This question has got 5 downvotes at this time. Can anyone suggest how I can improve it, and avoid a similar fate befalling any future ones?

[Are these apparent mistakes in The Haunting of Bly Manor deliberate?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/114174/are-these-apparent-mistakes-in-the-haunting-of-bly-manor-deliberate)